# method 'acquire' of '_thread.lock' objects is too slow in NN training with pytorch and ffcv

Tags: python, pytorch

I am training an NN on 1 Nvidia GPU using python, pytorch and the ffcv data loader, and the time for one iteration varies by a factor of 30, which makes some (many) of the training instances much longer than others.

In order to track down the source of the slow-down, I profiled the run using cProfile, and the most time is spent in the function `method 'acquire' of '_thread.lock' objects`. The time spent in the this function per call varies at least from 0.015s (for a run that happened to be fast) to 0.124 (for a run that happened to be slow), so roughly a factor of 10.

The per-iteration time varies across instances but also within instances (*i.e.* one training slows down/accelerates).

What can be the cause for this? (All the parameters were identical) Is there a way to control it, or at least mitigate the slow-down?

For reference, here are the first rows of the output of the profiling, sorted by `cumtime`:

- one small training, fast:

```
6618917 function calls (5423678 primitive calls) in 119.280 seconds

   Ordered by: cumulative time
   List reduced from 1214 to 100 due to restriction <100>

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    0.065    0.065  119.280  119.280 ./train.py:261(do_training)
     1565    0.018    0.000   92.495    0.059 .../.conda/envs/ffcv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ffcv/loader/epoch_iterator.py:140(__next__)
     1565    0.023    0.000   92.258    0.059 .../.conda/envs/ffcv/lib/python3.9/queue.py:154(get)
     1142    0.015    0.000   92.211    0.081 .../.conda/envs/ffcv/lib/python3.9/threading.py:280(wait)
     6134   92.190    0.015   92.190    0.015 {method 'acquire' of '_thread.lock' objects}
     1564    0.134    0.000   22.608    0.014 ./models/ssl.py:560(step)
136068/3128    0.468    0.000   21.914    0.007 .../.conda/envs/ffcv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py:1124(_call_impl)
     1562    0.022    0.000   20.810    0.013 ./models/ssl.py:259(test_step)
     1564    0.279    0.000   15.438    0.010 .../.conda/envs/ffcv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/nn/parallel/data_parallel.py:147(forward)
     1564    0.010    0.000   11.614    0.007 ./models/encoder.py:55(forward)
     1564    0.074    0.000   11.593    0.007 ./models/resnet.py:32(forward)
10948/6256    0.076    0.000    8.878    0.001 ...e/.conda/envs/ffcv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/container.py:137(forward)
    12512    0.529    0.000    8.759    0.001 .../.conda/envs/ffcv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torchvision/models/resnet.py:89(forward)
    31280    0.095    0.000    7.447    0.000 .../.conda/envs/ffcv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/conv.py:456(forward)
    31280    0.078    0.000    7.315    0.000 .../.conda/envs/ffcv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/conv.py:448(_conv_forward)
    31280    7.237    0.000    7.237    0.000 {built-in method torch.conv2d}
```

- one small training, slow:

```
2570224 function calls (2396817 primitive calls) in 1005.364 seconds

   Ordered by: cumulative time
   List reduced from 1250 to 100 due to restriction <100>

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    0.076    0.076 1005.364 1005.364 ./train.py:261(do_training)
     1565    0.025    0.000  972.119    0.621 .../.conda/envs/ffcv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ffcv/loader/epoch_iterator.py:140(__next__)
     1565    0.033    0.000  971.742    0.621 .../.conda/envs/ffcv/lib/python3.9/queue.py:154(get)
     1565    0.026    0.000  971.675    0.621 .../.conda/envs/ffcv/lib/python3.9/threading.py:280(wait)
     7827  971.640    0.124  971.640    0.124 {method 'acquire' of '_thread.lock' objects}
     1564    0.159    0.000   26.123    0.017 ./models/ssl.py:560(step)
136068/3128    0.650    0.000   25.136    0.008 .../.conda/envs/ffcv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py:1124(_call_impl)
     1562    0.021    0.000   22.797    0.015 ./models/ssl.py:259(test_step)
     1564    0.104    0.000   18.512    0.012 .../.conda/envs/ffcv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/nn/parallel/distributed.py:973(forward)
     1564    0.023    0.000   17.731    0.011 .../.conda/envs/ffcv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/nn/parallel/distributed.py:959(_run_ddp_forward)
     1564    0.014    0.000   17.501    0.011 ./models/encoder.py:55(forward)
     1564    0.120    0.000   17.466    0.011 ./models/resnet.py:32(forward)
10948/6256    0.111    0.000   14.324    0.002 .../.conda/envs/ffcv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/container.py:137(forward)
    12512    0.756    0.000   14.152    0.001 .../.conda/envs/ffcv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torchvision/models/resnet.py:89(forward)
    31280    0.142    0.000   11.407    0.000 .../.conda/envs/ffcv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/conv.py:456(forward)
    31280    0.107    0.000   11.207    0.000 .../.conda/envs/ffcv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/conv.py:448(_conv_forward)
    31280   11.100    0.000   11.100    0.000 {built-in method torch.conv2d}
```

- one big training, slow:

```
9393663 function calls (9055831 primitive calls) in 2093.533 seconds

   Ordered by: cumulative time
   List reduced from 1276 to 100 due to restriction <100>

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
      335    0.007    0.000 1942.907    5.800 .../.conda/envs/ffcv/lib/python3.9/threading.py:280(wait)
      344    0.007    0.000 1942.901    5.648 .../.conda/envs/ffcv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ffcv/loader/epoch_iterator.py:140(__next__)
     1692 1942.898    1.148 1942.898    1.148 {method 'acquire' of '_thread.lock' objects}
      344    0.008    0.000 1942.836    5.648 .../.conda/envs/ffcv/lib/python3.9/queue.py:154(get)
       42    0.002    0.000   48.570    1.156 ./train.py:238(save_checkpoint)
       84    0.008    0.000   48.519    0.578 ./train.py:362(save_checkpoint_data)
       84    0.016    0.000   48.490    0.577 .../.conda/envs/ffcv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/serialization.py:333(save)
      160    0.001    0.000   44.991    0.281 .../.conda/envs/ffcv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/_tensor.py:340(backward)
      160    0.001    0.000   44.990    0.281 .../.conda/envs/ffcv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/autograd/__init__.py:85(backward)
      160   44.985    0.281   44.985    0.281 ...._EngineBase' objects}
       84    0.001    0.000   41.014    0.488 .../.conda/envs/ffcv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/serialization.py:213(__exit__)
       84   41.014    0.488   41.014    0.488 {method 'close' of '_io.BufferedWriter' objects}
      160    0.001    0.000   20.002    0.125 .../.conda/envs/ffcv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/cuda/amp/grad_scaler.py:288(step)
      160    0.002    0.000   20.000    0.125 .../.conda/envs/ffcv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/cuda/amp/grad_scaler.py:282(_maybe_opt_step)
     1953    0.008    0.000   18.784    0.010 {built-in method builtins.sum}
```